# SVG css rotation sticking and not rotating about the center

Tags: html, css, svg, rotation, hover

When hovering an SVG, I want it to rotate the "container" with its contents not rotating. I tried countering the rotation of the SVG by counter rotating its contents but hit 2 issues:

1. They're not rotating about the center
2. They're not returning back to normal state when not hovered

The code

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path fill="none" d="M3.413,38.529c5.209,0.385,9.601-0.822,13.745-3.913c-4.223-0.565-7.115-2.503-8.675-6.429
                            c1.299-0.079,2.432-0.152,3.565-0.221c-4.248-1.805-6.697-4.756-7.021-9.438c1.334,0.364,2.572,0.701,3.81,1.04
                            C4.879,15.036,4.053,11.071,6.413,6.89c2.508,2.842,5.321,5.241,8.694,6.936c3.343,1.679,6.848,2.698,10.673,2.869
                            c0.068-1.372-0.044-2.736,0.23-4.018c1.527-7.146,9.775-10.025,15.383-5.375c0.745,0.617,1.363,0.77,2.219,0.433
                            c1.438-0.567,2.896-1.09,4.476-1.681c-0.582,1.976-1.881,3.367-3.404,4.605c0.053,0.102,0.105,0.205,0.157,0.307
                            c1.424-0.38,2.848-0.761,4.271-1.142c0.071,0.063,0.146,0.125,0.218,0.188c-1.164,1.208-2.237,2.528-3.527,3.583
                            c-0.84,0.686-0.98,1.387-0.984,2.344c-0.035,11.2-7.32,21.553-17.745,25.263C19.443,43.916,9.997,42.932,3.413,38.529z"></path>
</svg>
```

see [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Db2s2/)

Note: only works on `-webkit-` browsers at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its specific of SVG CSS Transformation. You can read about it [here](http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.com/2012/03/css-transform-origin-coming-to-svg.html).

You need define `transform-origin` property.

Fix for your case: http://jsfiddle.net/Db2s2/3/

Comment: Both answers nailed it, but you got in there first and also helped me solve another problem I had with "transform-origin" which I was unaware of!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want something to rotate then just stick it in a container that doesn't rotate.

I.e. stick another SVG on top as the container and rotate that.

```
<svg id="foreground" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" pointer-events="all">
</svg>
```

[like so](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/vyNkL/)