# CSS to flip (rotate) horizontally an SVG from center only works with image

Tags: css, animation, svg

I found someone's jsfiddle to do this with an image but it doesn't work for my SVG.

```
transform: rotateY(-360deg);
```

It rotates on the far left edge **instead of the center**. I assume this is because of SVG paths working differently to an image but...

Is the a workaround to make the SVG rotate like the image is, from the center?

My fiddle to illustrate issue: https://jsfiddle.net/t0bz/Ldm0ytft/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG css rotation sticking and not rotating about the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954895/svg-css-rotation-sticking-and-not-rotating-about-the-center)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its specific of SVG CSS Transformation. You can read about it [here](http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/css-transform-origin-coming-to-svg.html).

You need define transform-origin property.

```
`transform-origin: center center; `
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldm0ytft/2/

Comment: This property helped me to horizontally flip a part of an svg (a path) correctly based on the paths center. `transform-origin="center center" transform="scale(-1, 1)"`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `transform-origin` property and it should work well.

```
transform-origin: center center;
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldm0ytft/1/)

---

Just to add why it exactly is not working in your example is because you are using `class="slidecaption"` on `path` but you need to use it on your `svg` element.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldm0ytft/3/) (without using `transform-origin` property)

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King Sorry, I don't see it

Comment: Odd - per jsfiddle showed me the wrong version? I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

> The transform-origin property allows you to change the position of
>   transformed elements.
>
> 2D transformations can change the x- and y-axis of an element. 3D
>   transformations can also change the z-axis of an element.

So you can do it Using `transform-origin: center center;`

Also here is browser support table if you worry about using in old browsers:

`[image]

For more info about transform-origin,visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)